# How to implement dragdetection on Slider without using dragdetect listener?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-gef, draw2d

I want to implement a dragdetect on Slider widget. So when user drags the thumb. the drag should be detected. can anyone suggest a workaround with out using the drag detect listener.

thanks

regards
Bharath Y

Answer (score 0):

`org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Slider#addSelectionListener(SelectionListener)` is what you're looking for.